# Scraping interactive website

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrap name of the course with number of students from [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/courses/all) to find out which courses are the most popular. I manage to create code for item:

```
import scrapy
class UdacityItem(scrapy.Item):
    name=scrapy.Field()
    users=scrapy.Field()
```

and spider:

```
import scrapy
from Udacity.items import UdacityItem
import re

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "UdSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["udacity.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.udacity.com/courses/all"]

    def parse(self, response):

        sites = response.xpath('//h3/a')
        for s in sites:
            t=UdacityItem()
            #name & url
            t['name']=s.xpath('text()').extract()[0].strip()
            url=response.urljoin(s.xpath('@href').extract()[0])
            #request
            req=scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.second)
            req.meta['item']=t
            #execute
            yield req 

    def second(self,response):
        t=response.meta['item']
        strong =response.xpath('//strong[@data-course-student-count]/text()').extract()[0]
        t['users']=strong
        yield t
```

As a result I'm getting name of the course but instead of the number of students I am getting text 'thousands of'. When I open an [example website](https://www.udacity.com/course/javascript-promises--ud898) in browser I see that 'thousands of' is the base value and later (in 1-2 sec) this text is changing into a proper number(which I want to get).

And here are my questions:

1. Why this replacement is happening? Is this JavaScript code? I would
   like to understand mechanism of this change.
2. How I can capture proper number of students using scrapy? I hope this is possible.

Thank you in advance for help with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the enrollments count, you would have to simulate the API request to `https://www.udacity.com/api/summaries` endpoint for a specific course id, which can be extracted from the URL itself - for example, it is `ud898` for the `https://www.udacity.com/course/javascript-promises--ud898` URL.

Complete spider:

```
import json

import re
from urllib import quote_plus

import scrapy


class UdacityItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    users = scrapy.Field()


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "UdSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["udacity.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.udacity.com/courses/all"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//h3/a')
        for s in sites:
            t = UdacityItem()
            # name & url
            t['name'] = s.xpath('text()').extract()[0].strip()
            url = response.urljoin(s.xpath('@href').extract()[0])
            # request
            req = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.second)
            req.meta['item'] = t
            # execute
            yield req

    def second(self, response):
        queries = [{
            "limit": 1,
            "model": "CourseStudentsSummary",
            "locator": {
                "sample_frequency": "daily",
                "content_context": [{
                    "node_key": re.search(r'--(.*?)$', response.url).group(1)
                }]
            }
        }]
        yield scrapy.Request(method="GET",
                             url="https://www.udacity.com/api/summaries?queries=" + quote_plus(json.dumps(queries)),
                             callback=self.parse_totals)

    def parse_totals(self, response):
        print(json.loads(response.body[5:].strip())["summaries"]["default"][0]["data"]["total_enrollments"])
```

Comment: Dear alecxe. Thank you for the reply. Now I have solution but still I don't see a link between loading the html and sending API request. When I am looking at the document I can't find the code responsible for that. How you figure out that you need to make an API request? I guess that the JavaScript code is responsible for that which is loaded at the end of document, am I right?

Comment: @michalk I've used browser developer tools - Network tab and filtered XHR requests only; there are several XHR requests made during the page load, I've inspected them and found the total enrollments inside the response. Then, worked into making the same request in Scrapy..hope that helps.